# Best practice handeling an empty select with null stored as int in a postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, html, database

I'm not finding a convenient way to my basic problem.

I'm building an todo app with svelte and postgreSQL. All todos can have an status. My todo table having one field to a FK named status_id that is refering to the table status PK that is an nullable int.

```
CREATE TABLE todo(
    todo_id BIGSERIAL,
    title varchar(255),
    status_id smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY(todo_id)
);

ALTER TABLE todo
    ADD CONSTRAINT status_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (status_id)
    REFERENCES status (status_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL;

CREATE TABLE status (
    status_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    status varchar(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (gtd_id)
);
```

This is all great. A status is not mandatory and defaults to null.

Problem arise in the svelte components. In my  list, I cannot use null - instead I'm checking for null values with an if statement and replacing with the string "null".

```
<select bind:value={todo.status_id} >
   <option value="null">- No choice -</option>
   (Loop other options) ... 
</select>
```

When posting an update of the todo, I'm doing the opposite, checking for the string "null" and repleacing with null since I'm not able to store a string in my int database field.

Then, when It comes to sorting - I'm having my todo array with status_id:s and the string "null" making me having todo a custom array sort. Most of my todos metadata will be sortable and will have the same problem.

I find myself having to deal with this in several places. Sorting data when fetched from the db needs to handle null, and sorting my actual array variable later on via a sorting menu handles the string "null".

How do I code this without having to convert values back and forth?